# Using "Difference" in Geoprocessing Tools results in Minidump

Tags: qgis

I want to use this tool on 2 vector layers but as soon as I start the process I get a minidump and I have to close QGIS.

Does the .dmp file help you in solving this? Or can I open it and look for myself? But which program do I use to open it?

Comment: Which operating system and QGIS version are you using? Did you check the layers for geometric errors?

Comment: In my experience minidumps are usually caused by running out of memory - you could try breaking your data down a bit.

Comment: I updated Qgis from 2.14.1 to 2.14.3 and now it works!

Comment: I updated Qgis from 2.14.1 to 2.14.3 and now it works!